# My service stop after the back button

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have a service and an activity that communicate.
When I click the button(I have galaxy s3 there is only one button) then my activity of course disapear and my service is keep running but if I click the back (touch) button then my service is destroyed.
How can I change that?I want the service to keep running untill the activity destroys it.

**EDIT**

Here is the code:

Service:
    public class MyService  extends Service
    {
        private static final String TAG = "BroadcastService";
        public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.websmithing.broadcasttest.displayevent";
        private final Handler handler = new Handler();
        private Intent intent;
        int counter = 0;

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
    {
       // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second

    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayLoggingInfo();           
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 10 seconds
        }
    };    

    private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
        intent.putExtra("counter", String.valueOf(++counter));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);       
        super.onDestroy();
    }       
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastTest";
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

        startService(intent);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateUI(intent);       
        }
    };    


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        stopService(intent);        
    }   

    private void updateUI(Intent intent) 
    {
        String counter = intent.getStringExtra("counter"); 
        Log.d(TAG, counter);

        TextView txtCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtCounter.setText(counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some code

Comment: how are you starting your service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcourse your service stops, when you press the back button. The back button most calls `finish()` on the activity, and it is destroyed. When you press the other button (the home button), it just minimizes your app, and it will be only destroyed later, when the OS wants to free up space.

If you want to keep your service running, make it a foreground service, and dont stop it on activity destroy.

Comment: Ok thanks but now after I click the back button and come back looks like I got 2 services since the amount of data I receive is doubled. why is that?

Comment: You should make an option for it in your app to stop your service, or tie the stopping of your service to some condition in your `onDestroy()`. To make it foreground, you just have to call `startForeground(notificationId, notification)` in `onStart(...)` and `onStartCommand(...)` in your `Service`, and pass the method a status bar notification that will be visible while your service is running.

Comment: I just stoped the service when it gets to 100(it's a counter from 0) and the rreason that I got 2 services is that this line was disabled:  handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI); on the onStart method of the service. It's working now but do you think I've done it well?

Answer (score 4):

you can put your app in the background instead off finishing it.

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     moveTaskToBack(true);
    // super.onBackPressed();
    }
```