# Android window overlay error.Destroying surface without window. device real

Tags: android

**In emulator no error.**
 auto exit when exit app, i don't want.People can help me.
A background service in Android stops running when the user exits the app using the BACK button. The same service works fine if the app is in foreground or in background (clicking the HOME button).

there are 3 cases:

Keep the app running: every 15 seconds a notification is shown (OK).
Put the app in background by clicking the HOME button: notifications keep showing (OK)
Click the BACK button (this closes the app): the background service is stopped and no more notifications are shown (BUG)
Expected behavior

Also in case #3, the notifications should keep running every 15 seconds.

my entire source is below

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.javacodegeeks.android.androidserviceexample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.javacodegeeks.android.androidserviceexample.MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
           >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Myservice

```
 package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidserviceexample;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        final ImageView viewGallery = new ImageView(this);
        viewGallery.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        windowManager.addView(viewGallery, params);

        viewGallery.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX
                            + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY
                            + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(viewGallery, params);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...
        Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192853/my-service-stop-after-the-back-button

Comment: yes.i use Notification into service public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {}